# Why can't I access anonymous function objects?

Tags: javascript

I'm trying to understand why I can't access an anonymous function's Object.

An Example :

```
let Run=(distance)=>{
    console.log(`Mr ${this.name} is coming to the end of a very long road, After more than ${distance}.`)
}

let Runner = {name:'Forest Gump',Run}

Runner.Run('15,000 miles')
```

This return :

an empty object :

*`Mr  is coming to the end of a very long road, After more than 15,000 miles.`*

But when i change the function to :

```
function Run(distance){

    console.log(`Mr ${this.name} run ${distance}`)}
```

It works perfectly

Can someone explain to me why when doing anonymous function we can't access the object ?

Thank you.

Comment: The **this** keyword in the first function is not bound to any context. By definition arrow functions do not have their own **this**. you need to bind it. What you are trying to do is append an arrow function to an object. The **this** keyword has no outer context to point to. So it needs to be wrapped in a normal function.

Comment: It's because `this` means something different in ES6 arrow functions. https://medium.freecodecamp.org/when-and-why-you-should-use-es6-arrow-functions-and-when-you-shouldnt-3d851d7f0b26

Comment: Basically replace `let Run=(distance)=>{` with `let Run=function(distance){`

Answer (score 1):

This is because arrow functions do not have their own `this`. `this` in arrow functions are decided based on it's lexical scoping (ie, based on how your arrow function is enclosed), not based on how the function is called.

[MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/Arrow_functions) is having detailed documentation about this feature of arrow functions.